# How to load only IDs when use many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

I have the following models:

```cs
class Item
{
    public ICollection<string> GroupIds { get; set; }

    // Introduced for EF only
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

class Group
{
    public ICollection<string> ItemIds { get; set; }

    // Introduced for EF only
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Store
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Store contains all `Items` and all `Groups`, but every `Item` may be related with one or multiple `Group` and every `Group` may be related with one or multiple `Item`.

How I can configure many-to-many relationship between `Item` and `Group` to load only `GroupIds` and `ItemIds`, but not objects itself?

Comment: Duplicate, which means: you can't make EF to use the `string[]` properties and the other array properties should be `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Well, that doesn't matter. I can use ICollection<string> and ICollection<Item>, ICollection<Group>, question still be the same

Comment: I'm asked not about how to configure many-to-many relationship, but how to have IDs only without loading objects themselves

Comment: OK, reopened, but then I'm not sure what you're asking. What I do know is that you can't map your current model with EF.